# ansible is not looking at the collections defined in the collections-path in ansible.cfg

Tags: ansible, ansible-collections

I have local collections folder in my ansible playbook folder. I also configured the path in the ansible.cfg.

```
cat ansible.cfg
[defaults]
collections_paths = ./ansible_collections
```

But when I run the playbook, it uses the path from python site-packages

```
/Users/user1/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible_collections
```

I am running

```
ansible 2.10.11
  config file = /Users/user1/Documents/work/scripts/ansible-repo/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/user1/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Users/user1/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /Users/user1/opt/miniconda3/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.1
```

As part of the debugging the playbook run, I deleted the collections under site-packages and my playbook started to fail.

ansible-playbook run with detailed debug shows

```
  Using module file /Users/user1/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible_collections/arista/eos/plugins/modules/eos_command
```

ansible-galaxy collection list shows both the local collections and the collections under site-packages.

In the playbook, my task uses FQCN. For example arista.eos.eos_facts:

I have also manually set the ANSIBLE_COLLECTIONS_PATH variable.

```
env | grep ANSIBLE_COLLECTIONS_PATH
ANSIBLE_COLLECTIONS_PATHS=/Users/user1/Documents/work/scripts/ansible-repo/ansible_collections
```

Comment: Your local folder declared as path should actually be called (for better legibility...) `./collections` and should contain a `ansible_collections` folder containing itself one folder for each namespace and collections inside. This is a requirement clearly specified in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#collections-paths)

Comment: Thats solved the issue. Thanks.